# how to track file changes and registry changes to the system?

Tags: windows

hi guys i have a test system at work which is used to test final builds. I am wondering if there is a way to track if someone dumps a file on the system... I don't care if it tracks it for entire system or a specific directory any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Use FileSystemWatcher Class. It looks for different changes in folder.